# Xcode 10 - UITests - Reason: image not found

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods, cocoapods-1.6

I'm trying to run the `UITests` for my App but it's crashing as soon as it loads. Here's the error.

```
2018-09-29 16:19:49.577151+1000 xxxUITests-Runner[6007:69633] (dlopen_preflight(/Users/Acc/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/xxx-bjuwemcifadxhlhgojgfktmmades/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/xxxUITests-Runner.app/PlugIns/xxxUITests.xctest/xxxUITests): Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftContacts.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/Acc/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/xxx-bjuwemcifadxhlhgojgfktmmades/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/xxxUITests-Runner.app/PlugIns/xxxUITests.xctest/Frameworks/MapboxGeocoder.framework/MapboxGeocoder
  Reason: image not found)
```

I'm using `CocoaPods (v1.6.0.beta.1)` to install my frameworks. I'm running `Xcode 10` with `Swift 4.2` and `iOS 12`. Also, `Git` is used as version control with other developers (Perhaps there're conflicts?).

My target app works perfectly, both on a simulator and a real phone, and so does my unit tests. But my UITest target fails as soon as it launches up. This problem happens on both a simulator and a real machine.

There have been many posts on the issue before, but none of them have helped me so far. I've had 2 isolated occurrences before, the first time I've solved by adding dependencies into my pod file for the UITest unit, and the second time by simply removing my target and copy & pasting the classes back into the new target (unconstructive, but last resort). I can do the same this time as well but it's a bit of a waste of time and I'm afraid that this will crop up again in the future.

This is what I've done so far:

1. Clean Xcode builds folder and deleted derived data, IOS device logs, and User Data folders.
2. Restarted Xcode, Mac, as well as my device and simulators, and recloned repository, and pod update && pod install
3. Have 'Always embed swift standard libraries' as yes
4. Checked my Target Application is correct
5. Made sure offending framework (MapboxGeocoder.framework) is included in Embed Pod Frameworks

Comment: For reference, this seems to be tracked on [CocoaPods#8139](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/8139).

Answer (score 50, accepted):

So after 5 days, I managed to solve my own problem.

I solved it by moving my UITests target out of the scope of my main app in Podfile.

From:

```
target 'App' do
    use_frameworks!

    pods 'Firebase'

    target 'AppUITests' do
        pods 'Testingpod'
    end
end
```

To:

```
target 'App' do
    use_frameworks!

    pods 'Firebase'
end

target 'AppUITests' do
    pods 'Testingpod'
end
```

Comment: You deserve a cookie @qunayu

Comment: Any supporting reason to bring UITest target out of App target?

Comment: Brilliant! You made my day!

Answer (score 6):

Has found another solution suggested in Cocoapods issue.

As my project is a framework, so the test does not have a host application.

Changed Podfile

```
target 'framework' do
    use_ frameworks!
    pods my_dependencies
    target 'framework_tests' do
        inherit! :search_paths
    end
end
```

To

```
target 'framework' do
    use_ frameworks!
    pods my_dependencies
    target 'framework_tests'
end
```

https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/8139